# Автоувеличение id при добавлении строки в DBGrid

Tags: c++builder, oracle, база-данных, sql

Столбец id загружается из базы данных с помощью select.
Нужно при добавлении новой строки в DBGrid увеличивать его на единицу, то есть вычислить наибольшее значение и прибавить единицу. 
Как это сделать?

Comment: сиквенс

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас должна быть автонумеруемая колонка ID в таблице(-ах), с которой работаете. Для этого в Oracle используются последовательности (*sequences*, сиквенсы). См. ответ [@Chupa](/users/1867/chupa). ;-)

Вычислять максимальное число не совсем корректно с точки зрения уникальности, поэтому последовательности&nbsp;&mdash; наиболее правильный путь. При добавлении записи вам для нужной последовательности необходимо вызвать функцию `nextval`.

См. также [похожий вопрос](http://www.sql.ru/forum/actualthread.aspx?tid=655934) на sql.ru.